# GWT framework with data visualization capability

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am looking to find out which GWT framework is the easiest to use for someone with very little front end knowledge. I am looking to quickly and easily build a website mockup with dynamic graphs and charts. I will also need common form elements such and checkboxes and radio buttons etc.

I am not a front end developer. java is the only language I know, but I need to get a website mock-up up and running quickly. I know only a tiny amount of HTML and CSS. Performance is also important. Whichever GWT framework has the easiest learning curve for somebody with little or no knowledge of front end would be desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Roddy wrote in his comment, GWT itself is already a good way to go. I use it in a project where I have to visualize small to medium amounts of data from an oracle database.

In combination with the [GWT Designer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/) you will be able to create a working and good-looking application quickly, which will suit your needs I think.

As for charts, I can recommend [GFlot](http://code.google.com/p/gflot/%20GFlot), that's a GWT wrapper for the JavaScript library Flot. This way you can generate good-looking and customizable charts. I have successfully tested it with about 5,000 data points in a bar chart.